# Is the first address of the subnet a valid configurable address in case of IPv4 and IPv6 point to point networks?

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ipv6, ip-address

Am I correct, that first address of the subnet is a valid addresses to configure in hosts/routers in case of IPv4 and IPv6 point to point networks? For example, in case of `192.0.2.0/31` one of the hosts would get `192.0.2.0/31` and the other would get `192.0.2.1/31`. Or in case of `2001:db8::/127`, one of the devices would get the address `2001:db8::/127` and the other would get the `2001:db8::1/127`. In other words, the `192.0.2.0` or `2001:db8::` is a completely normal address?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/51985/8499), and the section on `/31` networks in [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53995/8499).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

### IPv4:

[*RFC 3021, Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021) explains it for IPv4, but be aware that not all vendors, in particular Microsoft, support `/31` networks:

> **2. Considerations of 31-Bit Prefixes**
>
> This section discusses the possible effects, on Internet routing and
> operations, of using 31-bit prefixes on point-to-point links. The
> considerations made here are also reflected in [Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021#section-3).
>
> For the length of this document, an IP address will be interpreted as:
>
> ```
>    <Network-number><Host-number>
> ```
>
> where the `<Host-number>` represents the unmasked portion of the
> address and it SHOULD be at least 1 bit wide. The "-1" notation is
> used to mean that the field has all 1 bits. For purposes of this
> discussion, the routing system is considered capable of classless, or
> CIDR [[RFC1519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1519)], routing.
>
> **2.1. Addressing**
>
> If a 31-bit subnet mask is assigned to a point-to-point link, it
> leaves the `<Host-number>` with only 1 bit. Consequently, only two
> possible addresses may result:
>
> ```
>    {<Network-number>, 0} and {<Network-number>, -1}
> ```
>
> These addresses have historically been associated with network and
> broadcast addresses (see [Section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021#section-2.2)). In a point-to-point link
> with a 31-bit subnet mask, the two addresses above MUST be interpreted
> as host addresses.
>
> **2.2. Broadcast and Network Addresses**
>
> There are several historically recognized broadcast addresses
> [[RFC1812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812)] on IP segments:
>
> ```
>   (a) the directed broadcast
>
>        {<Network-number>, -1}
>
>        {<Network-number>, 0}
>
>      The network address itself {<Network-number>, 0} is an
>      obsolete form of directed broadcast, but it may still be used
>      by older hosts.
>
>   (b) the link local (or limited) broadcast
>
>        {-1, -1}
>
>        {0, 0}
>
>      The {0, 0} form of a limited broadcast is obsolete, but may
>      still be present in a network.
> ```
>
> Using a 31-bit prefix length leaves only two numbering possibilities
> (see [Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021#section-2.1)), eliminating the use of a directed broadcast to
> the link (see [Section 2.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021#section-2.2.1)). The limited broadcast MUST be used
> for all broadcast traffic on a point-to-point link with a 31-bit
> subnet mask assigned to it.
>
> The `<Network-number>` is assigned by the network administrator as
> unique to the local routing domain. The decision as to whether a
> destination IP address should be a directed broadcast or not is made
> by the router directly connected to the destination segment. Current
> forwarding schemes and algorithms are not affected in remote routers.
>
> The intent of this document is to discuss the applicability and
> operation of 31-bit prefixes on point-to-point links. The effects (if
> any) on other types of interfaces are not considered.
>
> **2.2.1. Directed Broadcast**
>
> When a device wants to reach all the hosts on a given (remote, rather
> than directly connected) subnet, it may set the packet's destination
> address to the link's subnet broadcast address.  This operation is not
> possible for point-to-point links with a 31-bit prefix.
>
> As discussed in [Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021#section-6), the loss of functionality of a
> directed broadcast may actually be seen as a beneficial side effect,
> as it slightly enhances the network's resistance to a certain class of
> DoS Attacks[[RFC2644](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2644), [SMURF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021#ref-SMURF)].
>
> **2.3. Impact on Current Routing Protocols**
>
> Networks with 31-bit prefixes have no impact on current routing
> protocols. Most of the currently deployed routing protocols have been
> designed to provide classless routing. Furthermore, the communication
> between peers is done using multicast, limited broadcast or unicast
> addresses (all on the local network), none of which are affected with
> the use of 31-bit subnet masks.

Think of it this way for IPv4, every packet sent on a `/31` network is actually destined for every other host (there is only one) on the network, which is the definition of a broadcast, so the broadcast doesn't matter on such a network.

---

### IPv6:

IPv6 never had broadcast, so, unlike IPv4, all the addresses in an IPv6 network are available as host addresses, including the all-zeroes and all-ones addresses. IPv6 makes heavy use of multicast.